# RavenDB: How to serialize a class differently when embedded versus as a document

Tags: ravendb

The sample db that comes with RavenDB has `Albums` document collection, that each have a `Genre` embedded document in it, like this:

```
{
  ... other stuff...
  "Genre": {
    "Id": "genres/1",
    "Name": "Rock"
  },
  ... other stuff...
}
```

Notice that here the `Genre` has `Id` and `Name` fields.

But when you look at `Genre` documents, they have `Id`, `Name`, and `Description` fields, like this:

```
{
  "Description": "Rock and Roll is a form of rock music developed in the 1950s and 1960s. Rock music combines many kinds of music from the United States, such as country music, folk music, church music, work songs, blues and jazz.",
  "Name": "Rock"
}
```

How can I model in code so that when I `Store()` then `SaveChanges()` that the `Genre` will be serialized and saved differently (like the example data) when saving its own document versus when saving the `Album` document and embedding the `Genre`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This model will match the ravendb sample data:

```
public class Genre
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public GenreRef Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CountSold { get; set; }
    public ArtistRef Artist { get; set; }

    public class GenreRef
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArtistRef
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example usage with includes:

```
var albumId = "albums/1";
var album = session.Include<Album>(x => x.Genre.Id)
                   .Load<Album>(albumId);
var genre = session.Load<Genre>(album.Genre.Id);
```

The include means that when loading the Genre, there is no db call because it's already tracked in the session.

Comment: hmm, understood, that could work. but that seems a little bit lame. In the model I'd like to be able to set the Album's Genre as a actual Genre type (reuse the Genre instance for storing as document and for embedding in to the album). Any way to do that?

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't work that way.  Genre and Album are the only documents.  They are "aggregates" in DDD terms.  The Reference class is not an aggregate or a document unto itself.  You could have GenreRef and ArtistRef as separate classes, but they are both part of the Album document.  For clarity, some people put them as nested classes within the aggregate so they don't interfere externally.

Comment: I updated the sample code to show the nested classes and separate reference classes as I described.  Also the Ids are properly shown as strings now.  Int ids would work, but are not the norm with Raven.

Comment: ok, so the answer is basically no, and in my model if I want an Artist property, I need to populate it after the initial query by using the ArtistRef

Comment: Yes, but you can "Include" it when you query so you only hit the database once.  You should review http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships  I updated the answer with an example.